# Resizing the Unity search box

Tags: unity, 16.04

Is there any way to resize the search box in unity, I'm not sure exactly what it is called but I have provided a picture to show my meaning. QUICK EDIT: I don't mean maximize it fullscreen, but resize it like you do with a normal window by dragging the corner or something like that.

[image: search box]

Comment: Duplicate of "How can I resize the unity dash"

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

**half screen unity search box**

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Desktop'
```

**fullscreen unity search box**

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Netbook'
```